# .NET Core 3 Service result to Controller to FE (data or error reason)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

building new app on .net core 3 and Angular. Overall all works, but I want to add more intelligence to service/controller part. This is one of the api's, but this logic can be applied to others as as well.
Here's my Login Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginDto userLogin)
        {
            var token = await _userService.LoginAsync(userLogin);
            if (token != null)
            {
                return Ok(token);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
```

And here's my userService:

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(UserLoginDto userLogin)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userLogin.Email);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, userLogin.Password, false, true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                    var tokenJson = _jwtManager.getJwtToken(user.Email, roles);
                    return tokenJson;
                }
                else
                {

                    return null; // Return BadRequest and result reason (Failed, lockedout, etc)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null; // User not found, return NotFound            }
        }
```

Here's my question - how should I return result from userService to Controller so, that I could respond to API call either with Ok(token) or BadRequest/NotFound with the reason.
If I keep all this LoginAsync code in controller, then it's easy, but I want to use service.
One option I was thinking was to introduce new class, something like:

```
    public class BaseResult
    {
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public long ResponseCode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

then always return this class from service, but not fully like that idea either.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class UserLoginDto
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

IUserService:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(UserLoginDto userLogin);
}
```

UserService:

```
public class UserService: IUserService
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IJwtManager _jwtManager;

    public UserService(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        IJwtManager jwtManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _jwtManager = jwtManager;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(UserLoginDto userLogin)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userLogin.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, userLogin.Password, false, true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                var tokenJson = _jwtManager.getJwtToken(user.Email, roles);
                return new OkObjectResult(tokenJson);
            }
            else
            {
                // Return BadRequest and result reason (Failed, lockedout, etc)
                if (result.IsNotAllowed)
                {
                    if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
                    {
                        // Email isn't confirmed.
                        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Email isn't confirmed.");
                    }

                    if (!await _userManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user))
                    {
                        // Phone Number isn't confirmed.
                        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Phone Number isn't confirmed.");
                    }
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Login IsNotAllowed");
                }
                else if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    // Account is locked out.
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Account is locked out.");
                }
                else if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    // 2FA required.
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult("2FA required");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Password is incorrect.
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Password is incorrect.");                       
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new NotFoundObjectResult("Username is incorrect"); // User not found, return NotFound            }
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public HomeController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginDto userLogin)
    {
        var result= await _userService.LoginAsync(userLogin);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

Not sure what is `_jwtManager.getJwtToken` in your code,so I just guess it is an interface and owns a `JwtManager` class implemented this interface.And it contains a `getJwtToken` method which generated the token.

```
services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
services.AddScoped<IJwtManager, JwtManager>();
```